# Is `std::string::iterator` guaranteed not to be a pointer to char?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, stl, containers

Given that an overload of `operator<<` on `std::ostream` for pointer to `char` exists, and given that the standard specifies the synopsis of the `std::string` class to be the following, in §21.4:

```
namespace std {
  template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT>,
    class Allocator = allocator<charT> >
  class basic_string {
  public:
    [...]
    typedef implementation-defined iterator;
    typedef implementation-defined const_iterator; 
    [...]
  };
}
```

and finally given that the requirements for `iterator` and `const_iterator` for a `Container` concept are, in §23.2/4:

[image]

and a pointer to `char` would satisfy them; am I reading it correctly that it's implementation defined whether the following code compiles or not?

```
std::string string = "abc";
std::cout << begin(string);
```

---

On a side note, both [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5caf47fcd144478) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dd7738cca17949c) seem not to accept it.

Comment: It is **not** _implementation defined_: the implementation is _not_ required document the type of the iterators. However, an implementation is _allowed_ to use a class or a pointer type.

Comment: @DietmarKühl If the type of the iterators is not implementation defined, then why, in the synopsis of `basic_string`, are they marked as "*implementation-defined*"?

Comment: Based on what you have already described in the post, I would say "yes" to your question in the post, and "no" to the question in the title.

Comment: Is an iterator a pointer?

Comment: IIRC before C++11, the underlying storage was not required to be null-terminated. So even if the iterator type was `char*`, you can't just assume it's a null-terminated string (pre-C++11 :))

Comment: @melak47 That's actually a very good point.

Comment: @KelvinLai Not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

That could depend on what you put in the wording "pointer to char". Either it could be strictly interpreted as the formal type `char*` or similar or more loosely as anything that's an address to memory where a character resides.

I don't see that the overload you're mentioning actually exists in the standard, but nevertheless it's possible that other required overloads exists. The one you takes as example doesn't seem to exist (and it doesn't seem to be any other places with overloads with `std::string::iterator` vs `char*`), you cant for example output a `std::string::iterator` for example:

```
std::string s = "abc";
std::string.iterator p = s.begin();

std::cout << p; // fails
```

Since the standard says that the methods and functions should exist and even if we take the requirement that the implementation need not actually formally define them the way that's indicated in the standard, but only to behave as if it were (compare the requirement of the translation sequence) you still probably would need to have the distinction of the overloads since you're supposed to be able to take a pointer to them (and you need to be able to know what type that pointer should have).

For example if we have a specification saying that it should behave as if `void foo(long)` and `void foo(int)` were defined and the implementation actually only contain `void foo(long)` it would work fine as long as the programs only issues functions calls to `foo` as shorts would silently be converted to `int`, but as soon as some program contains code to take a pointer to the function it would fail since the type it would store the pointer in simply wouldn't match:

```
 void foo(long);

 foo(1L); // works fine
 foo(1);  // works probably fine, 1 is converted to long first

 void (*f)(int) = foo;  // this fails as it cant convert void(*)(long) to void(*)int
```

From this we can conclude that `std::string::iterator` would probably need to be of a different formal type (still if there exists a overload on `char*` vs `std::string::iterator`). Note though that even if `char*` appears, that `char const*` is a distinct type.

However if you're just by "pointer to char" only means an address in memory of a character (not necessarily of the type `char*`) it certainly can be. One could even argue that it may be quite likely that it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, is half of your answer (first paragraph, last paragraph and second half of the third) about me saying "pointer to `char`" as opposed to "pointer to `const char`"?

Comment: @Jefffrey No, it's the possible distinction between "pointer to char" and `char*`, the former could be more liberally interpreted as I discuss in the last section.

Comment: Why is it relevant whether the overload is `char*`, "pointer to `char` or `CharT const*` (given a type name `CharT`)? To me it looks irrelevant so feel free to edit my question to make it clearer which overload would be picked by passing a `char*` if that's so important to you.

Comment: The second paragraph is a completely mistery to me. I have no idea what you are trying to say. Could you please rephrase it? What's "these" in the first line? What do you mean by "you still probably would need to have the distinction of the overloads since you're supposed to be able to take a pointer to them"?

Comment: The distinction is not that important to me, my answer cover both possibilities. If it's important to **you** that I don't cover both I think you should edit your question.

Comment: @Jefffrey Don't worry about the mystery, it just says that the library implementation need to have the same function signatures as stated in the standard regardless of interpretation. However the problematic method doesn't seem to exist - at all.

Answer (score 0):

The (actual) types of the `std::string`'s iterators are implementation defined.   There is no requirement that they be a pointer, and also no requirement that they not be a pointer.

There is also no requirement that the standard streams have a variant of `operator<<()` that accepts an iterator from any standard container (including `std::string`).   Conversely, there no requirement that it shall not.    Which means it is implementation-defined whether the code at the end of your post compiles.